# createJS button onclick not working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, buttonclick, createjs

I am new to createJS toolkit (Flash CS6), My concept is I have a multiple buttons on the stage, each button click will have different animations in different frames.

my code is

```
'/* js 
this.stop();
this.btnname.onPress = function()
{ this.parent.gotoAndPlay("cone"); }
*/'
```

it is perfectly working in all browsers and android mobile, but in iPhone it is not working,
I am trying to click on the button but canvas is highlighting in iphone,
when I change my code to the following code,

```
'/* js 
this.stop();
this.onPress = function()
{ this.gotoAndPlay("cone"); }
*/'
```

It is working in iPhone, but I have multiple button clicks, here is my major problem.

Please help me find a solution to this issue.

Comment: could you tell me whether you were using Shape class for your buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener` and listen for the "click" or "mousedown" event instead of assigning an `onPress` function. Like this:

```
/* js
this.stop();
this.btnname.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parent.gotoAndPlay("cone");
});
*/
```

Comment: no i did't get any errors, it is working in iOS 6 but i need in latest versions like iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a shape, cache it and use it as the hitArea of your button. john has answered your question here: http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/5663-touch-on-ios-only-seems-to-work-with-bitmaps